# PHP displaying script feedback - Undefined variable

Tags: php, html

I am quite new to php and I tried to find an answer for this but couldn't, if there is an answer already then I apologize.

I am building a simple website, just a few pages (login, register, home).

On the register form, once the submit button is pressed a PHP script checks if the email used for registration is already in the database, if it is I need to display some feedback to the user.

I have two files, a.php which is really just an html file for the page and b.php which is my script.

I am using session_start() in both of the files and I am displaying a $_SESSION variable in the html page which contains the feedback (i.e "Email already used").

However I keep getting an uninitialized variable warning since when the html page is first opened the $_SESSION variable does not exist yet.

How do I fix this? I do not want to use JS or AJAX at this stage, and would like to keep the files separate. **I am aware of what the error means.**

This is the code in a.php (the html page)

```
<p><?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION["message"];?></p>
```

This is the code in b.php (the script)

```
if($row){
    $_SESSION["message"] = "Email already used";
    header( 'Location: register.php' );
    exit();
}
```

Thank you.

**EDIT - SOLUTION:
Adding**

```
if(isset($_SESSION["message"])){echo $_SESSION["message"];}
```

**fixes the issue.**

Comment: You want us to tell you what's wrong with your code without showing us the code?

Comment: @Goofynose You should post your codes as well so that we can reproduce it and fix the problem...

Comment: I added the code. Please don't mark as duplicate, I know what the error is and how to remove it -> initialize the variable in the html file, but doing so just resets it and prevents me from using the value passed by the script.

Comment: Hey goofynose, before you echo `$_SESSION["message"]` check if the session variable is set as `if(isset($_SESSION["message"])) echo $_SESSION["message"];`.

Comment: @RatulDoley Thank you very much that fixes it! :)

Comment: Then mark the comment as useful...